# what is the max frequency of external interrupt for esp8266 arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, interrupt

i am using esp7 with AttachInterrupt() (Arduino) to count incremental encoder. I need to know what is the maximum frequency of pulses that esp7 can acquire.
also, need to know what frequency atmega328 can go with interrupt handling for an incremental encoder. my encoder 1000ppr.

Comment: This largely depends on what you are doing in the interrupt handler. Are you asking for the maximum frequency without any code in the ISR?

Comment: `my encoder 1000ppr.` ... this information is not relevant to the question.

Comment: On the 328 you can use the pulses as in input for timer2 (sync timer input). In that case the maximum frequency is one-fourth the frequency of what the 328 is running at. So 4MHz for the UNO.